# wait and pulse Exception in C#

Tags: c#, monitor, parallels

I have simulation druring time. in every steps I have 4 main function f1,f2,f3,f4. f1 must be run before all and f2 , f3 can run after f1 parallel. when f2 and f3 is finished can start f4.
I want create 4 task to do these. but I don't want create task in every step.(because it has overhead)
I want after do one task , wait for next step.
I write this code but give exception.

```
Task taskf1, taskf2, taskf3, taskf4;
    bool lockf1,lockf2, lockf3, lockf4_1,lockf4_2;
    Random r;
    public void f()
    {
        r = new Random();
        taskf1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(f1);
        taskf2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(f2);
        taskf3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(f3);
        taskf4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(f4);
        Monitor.Pulse(lockf1);

    }
    private void f1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(lockf1);
            Console.WriteLine("task 1");
            Thread.Sleep((int)(r.NextDouble() * 1000.0));
            Monitor.Pulse(lockf2);
            Monitor.Pulse(lockf3);
        }
    }
    private void f2()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(lockf2);
            Console.WriteLine("task 2");
            Thread.Sleep((int)(r.NextDouble() * 1000.0));
            Monitor.Pulse(lockf4_1);
        }
    }
    private void f3()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(lockf3);
            Console.WriteLine("task 3");
            Thread.Sleep((int)(r.NextDouble() * 1000.0));
            Monitor.Pulse(lockf4_2);
        }
    }
    private void f4()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(lockf4_1);
            Monitor.Wait(lockf4_2);
            Console.WriteLine("task 4");
            Thread.Sleep((int)(r.NextDouble() * 1000.0));
            Monitor.Pulse(lockf1);
        }
    }
```

I give exception in one of Monitor.Wait(lockfn)

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233064
Message=Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean exitContext, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Object obj)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(Object obj, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(Object obj)
   at parallel_Test.Program.f1() in c:\Users\Sharafi\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\parallel Test\parallel Test\Program.cs:line 191
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
InnerException:
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, but `Monitor.Wait` should be called only when you're holding a lock but your code doesn't seems to adhere it.

Comment: I want to block some task to ready variables.
what is your suggestion?

Comment: Can you use `async-await`? Don't block, just await for the task(preparing the variables required) to complete.

Comment: can you say more details. please give me code.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it what you are trying to achieve:

```
var firstTask = new Task(f1);
var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith(ignored => f2());
var thirdTask  = firstTask.ContinueWith(ignored => f3());
var fourthTask = Task.WhenAll(secondTask, thirdTask).ContinueWith(ignored => f4());

firstTask.Start();
```

Comment: I want in every step occur this Sequence. and don't create tasks in every step

Comment: Task is a unit of work. If you need something happening recurrently, use threads. What I don't understand is what's the problem with creation of tasks? The overhead you are talking about may be not worse than overhead of waiting for monitor signal. You will not know until you profile both scenarios.

Comment: in Thread how can wait one thread for two other threads reached one line?

Comment: Exactly like you are trying to do it with tasks. You provide a separate synchronization instance for each of the threads. It could be for example ManualResetEvent or Semaphore. But what you **don't use** are tasks.